# phpBB3 SQL database table doesn't exist ERROR; cannot import from backup or drop the broken database

Tags: mysql, database, macos, phpmyadmin, phpbb3

I installed phpBB3 to Mac OS X server (10.9) and it had been running fine since April until a few hours ago. I can't tell the exact cause of the problem, but it appeared that after installing OS X Server 10.9.4 update, somehow it's database lost its integrity. So I'll explain what happened and what I tried.

When I tried to access the forum I got the following error message.

```
General Error 
SQL ERROR [ mysql4 ]
Table 'phpbb3.phpbb_config' doesn't exist [1146]
An sql error occurred while fetching this page. Please contact an administrator if this problem persists.
```

Then I went to phpMyAdmin and clicked the database phpbb3. It said Table is missing. I didn't know how to fix it. So I used TimeMachine to recover the previous status of the system before OS X Server update. The forum was OK, but I blindly tried the OS update again and ended up with repeating the problem. I used TimeMachine again. This time the forum hasn't recovered. Meanwhile TimeMachine backup just became full and I realized that I lost all the TimeMachine backups but the latest one. This way, I can't get back to recover the phpBB3 forum any longer.

I gave up recovering with a TimeMachine backup and tried to recover the database by importing the last backup via phpMyAdmin. The backup was made 2 months ago, but still better than nothing. However, import didn't work either.

```
Error
SQL query:

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `phpbb_acl_groups` (
  `group_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `forum_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `auth_option_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `auth_role_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `auth_setting` tinyint(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  KEY `group_id` (`group_id`),
  KEY `auth_opt_id` (`auth_option_id`),
  KEY `auth_role_id` (`auth_role_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
MySQL said: Documentation

#1813 - Tablespace for table '`phpbb3`.`phpbb_acl_groups`' exists. Please DISCARD the tablespace before IMPORT.
```

Then I tried to delete the database phpbb3 but I failed.

```
Error 
SQL query: 
DROP DATABASE `phpbb3` MySQL said: Documentation

#1010 - Error dropping database (can't rmdir './phpbb3', errno: 66)
```

Finally, I found out where the actual database files are (`/usr/local/mysql/data/phpbb3`). I looked inside the folder and there are still bunch of files; all of them ended with `.ibd` extension, including `phpbb_acl_groups.ibd` (147 KB; this is the first one in the alphabetical order).

Here's my question: What should I do? Should I manually delete the `/usr/local/mysql/data/phpbb3` folder and try to import the latest (2 months ago) database export file? Or could I somehow recover the database from what left in `/usr/local/mysql/data/phpbb3` folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this article.

[mysqldump problems with restore error: 'Please DISCARD the tablespace before IMPORT'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17914446/mysqldump-problems-with-restore-error-please-discard-the-tablespace-before-imp)

It says that the folder `/usr/local/mysql/data/phpbb3` should contain `.ibd` files and `.frm` files. But the ERROR `Tablespace for table '`phpbb3`.`phpbb_acl_groups`' exists.` means `.frm` files are all gone. That was the case indeed.

So I judged that the folder `/usr/local/mysql/data/phpbb3` is no use any more. Now that all the TimeMachine backups are gone, the only way is to rely on the available database backup file. I forced to remove the folder from finder. Created the new empty database via phpMyAdmin, and then imported the database backup. This time there was no error and I was able to log on to the phpBB3 forum. Although I lost new data, the forum itself seems fine.

Answer (score -3):

MS SQL database recovery tool that easily performs SQL server database recovery from corrupt and lost tables, triggers, views, etc. This tool compatible with all MS SQL versions 2000, 2005 & 2008. For more details and free download click http://recoverydatatools.com/sql-recovery.html